# Ran out of fuel while riding, what's worst?

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-system

My bike(duke 390 2013) run out of fuel while I was riding it. It is the first time I'm experiencing this. So I'm a bit afraid about the fuel pump. I heard on diesel engines it could be a real problem, but what about the normal engines like mine? It happened few minutes ago, and I will be able to fill it tomorrow.

I am wondering what could have happened to my bike? I just pushed the button for 2-3 times to start it.

Comment: You're right, it can be a problem on some diesels. I've never heard of any bike using a diesel engine, so I can't image that would be an issue :-). Just fill her back up. You might have to try to start it a few times to get the fuel to the engine.

Comment: Most likely nothing maybe a little wear on the pump? but even then its very insignificant if any at all

Comment: Did you fill it up with diesel?? 

Comment: No I didn't fill it with diesel :) edited the question for that misunderstanding.

Comment: In some modern car engines that might be the problem, because pump might not be able to suck fuel when there is air in fuel lines. If yours won't start, that might be the cause. Typically it's easy to fix but might require hand pump to get the fuel into the fuel filter.

Comment: There is no damage to engine, when you run out of fuel. If it was carbureted engine, then there is no damage to carburator. As you have fuel enjected engine, then there is a little to no damage to fuel pump. On FI engines you want your fuel pump to be always in the fuel, it is designed so, that air should not get into it. Though once or twice will not do much damage.

Comment: @Ives They aren't very popular :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diesel_motorcycle